# How to know when the user is done with text entry on an EditText control?

Tags: android, kotlin

I want to be able to know when a user is done entering text in an EditText control. I'm thinking maybe it's best to know when the keyboard is closed or something similar. This is using Kotlin on Android app. I'm not sure why it's so hard to find basic answers like this. Maybe I'm searching with the wrong question (new to Android dev).

Comment: Maybe place a Button that the user should press after he's done?

Answer (score 0):

Using keyboard close as an indicator that the user finished entering text is a bad idea (the user might open the keyboard again to enter more text).  A better solution would be to explicitly require for the user to indicate that he has finished entering the data.

You could use a "submit" button.

You can also set the `android:imeOptions` of `EditText` to `actionDone` and set a listener on the `EditText`.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(EditText v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
    if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
       //do your stuff
       return true;
    }
    return false;
    } 
});
```

**Update** - Assuming keyboard close as the indicator is bad for a couple of reasons,

1. There is no 'proper' way to monitor the soft keyboard. You could try listening to the focus of the `EditText` or you could use the height difference to guesstimate whether the soft keyboard is open or closed(the option used in most keyboard listener libraries). But these aren't reliable and might break in production.
2. It's an 'unexpected' application behavior for the user. For example, the keyboard can be removed by pressing the back button. In general, the user would expect that the action would not proceed if the back button is pressed. But if you listen to keyboard close, then it would end up resulting in poorer UX.
3. There are no actual reasons why you would want to use keyboard close as the trigger. If you want to perform the action as the user types, then you should use `TextWatcher`, otherwise stick to explicit confirm options.

Comment: Why is that a bad idea? If they open it again, they still have to close it, and that's all I care about.

Comment: There are a couple of reasons, I'll add them to the answer.

Comment: Ok this helped. I ended up using TextWatcher with afterTextChanged and always check if the edit text is empty or not. It seems a bit inefficient to do this kind of thing, but probably the best way. Also, was looking for a solution using Kotlin not Java

Comment: I was just about to suggest TextWatcher as an alternative. Glad you found your answer, cheers mate.

Answer (score -1):

use onFocusChangeListener to know if the user has finished to add text and has leave the textInput focus.
Example

```
editText?.onFocusChangeListener =
        View.OnFocusChangeListener { _,
                                     hasFocus ->
            if (!hasFocus) {
                // code to execute when EditText loses focus
            }
        }
```